# Is a second kaddish recited on Yom Tob when there is only 1 Sefer Torah in the shul?

Tags: kaddish, sefer-torah

In a shul that has only 1 sefer Torah, is a second Kaddish recited on Yom Tob when finishing reading the second Torah portion for the day?

Comment: Hi samyb8, I'm not sure why you think the number of Torah scrolls and the number of recitations of kaddish might be related

Comment: Just to note, if I’ve understood the question correctly, that a second kaddish is a sefardic custom, when maftir is not simply a repetition of the end of the portion read that day